# How to convert Table Data into JSon Array in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have  sample  Data

```
ID    VAL    LINK
12   5335.1  2
12   5336.1  2
12   5337.1  2
```

Initially I have  tried  Using  GROUP_CONCAT on top of it  applied  Json_ARRAYAGG

```
Select  JSON_OBJECT('VAL',VAL,'LINK',LINK)AS COL 
from (
Select GROUP_CONCAT("",VAL,"")VAL,LINK from Table GROUP BY VAL,LINK ) T
```

I'm getting  output like this  :

```
[{"VAL": "5335.1,5336.1,5337.1", "LINK": 1}]
```

How can I convert this  into Json Array :

**Required Out Put**

```
[{
"VAL":["5335.1","5336.1","5337.1"],
"LINK":1
}]
```

Comment: Why try to do this in MySQL? MySQL is for generating records. Far better to parse the resultset into JSON via whatever programming language you're using to interface with MySQL.

Comment: I'm doing  in Database  Side  @mitya it is  required for  Store procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('VAL', JSON_ARRAYAGG(VAL), 'LINK', LINK) output
FROM source_table
GROUP BY LINK
```